# Adding line data to raster in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, line

I have a series of linear data sets; roads and rivers. I have buffered these to make them integratable with a raster file and then converted from a polyline to a raster.

But I can't get it to add to the raster image, which is a land cover classification. I've tried to mosaic it with the original raster but it doesn't work.

How should I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Throws an error? You use the Mosaic tool, I suspect you need to read the help file and understand the parameters of the tool. The _mosaic operator_ parameter would be a key parameter to alter.

Comment: It runs the system but then the output image does not show the linear features integrated

Comment: What bit depth are each of your raster datasets? What format (tiff, img, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Your rasterized polyline has probably been added successfully to the mosaic, but you might not see it because it overlaps with the land cover raster, and mosaicking rules display the land cover raster cells on top. See [Understanding the mosaicking rules for a mosaic dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/understanding-the-mosaicking-rules-for-a-mosaic-dataset.htm) for more details on how these rules work.

If what you want to do is update the land cover raster with cell values from the rasterized polyline (where available), you should use the [Con](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) tool:

> OutputRaster = Con(LineRaster, LineRaster, LandCoverRaster)

Don't forget to set the `Mask` environment property to `LandCoverRaster` in the tool, otherwise the output will have the extent of `LineRaster`.